# AJAX launch error as alert but with good response in array as string from php json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I try to send some text data and some files to PHP from JavaScript using AJAX by `FormData`. Also I try to send as response, array from PHP to JavaScript, so I use `json_encode()` in PHP and `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript. The code seems to work, but AJAX shows me the response from PHP in error alert, though the response is good. Here is my code:
JS:

```
var model = document.getElementById("model").value;
var numerfabryczny = document.getElementById("numer_fabryczny").value;
var data = document.getElementById("data_zakupu").value;
var imienazwisko = document.getElementById("imienazwisko").value;
var adres = document.getElementById("adres").value;
var tel = document.getElementById("numer_tel").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var opis = document.getElementById("opis").value;
var zal1 = $("#zal1").get(0).files[0];
var zal2 = $("#zal2").get(0).files[0];
var zal3 = $("#zal3").get(0).files[0];


var zal = new FormData();
zal.append('rodzaj', rodzaj);
zal.append('marka', marka);
zal.append('model', model);
zal.append('kategoria', kategoria);
zal.append('numerfabryczny', numerfabryczny);
zal.append('data', data);
zal.append('adres', adres);
zal.append('imienazwisko', imienazwisko);
zal.append('tel', tel);
zal.append('email', email);
zal.append('opis', opis);
zal.append('lang', lang);
zal.append('zal1', zal1);
zal.append('zal2', zal2);
zal.append('zal3', zal3);
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "php/sprawdz-naprawa.php",
        data: zal,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            var returnedData = data;

            rodzajerr.style.display = 'none';
            markaerr.style.display = 'none';
            kategoriaerr.style.display = 'none';
            modelerr.style.display = 'none';
            numererr.style.display = 'none';
            dataerr.style.display = 'none';
            imienazwiskoerr.style.display = 'none';
            adreserr.style.display = 'none';
            telerr.style.display = 'none';
            emailerr.style.display = 'none';
            opiserr.style.display = 'none';
            zal1err.style.display = 'none';
            zal2err.style.display = 'none';
            zal3err.style.display = 'none';

            if(returnedData=="ok")
            {
                alert("zgloszenie wysłano");
            }
            else
            {
                if(returnedData=="error")
                {
                    alert("wystąpił error");
                }
                else
                {
                    //returnedData=eval(data);
                    returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    //returnedData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    //returnedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //returnedData=$.parseJSON(data);
                    if(returnedData['rodzaj']!=""){rodzajerr.style.display = 'block'; rodzajerr.innerHTML =returnedData['rodzaj'];}else{rodzajerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['marka']!=""){markaerr.style.display = 'block'; markaerr.innerHTML =returnedData['marka'];}else{markaerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['kategoria']!=""){kategoriaerr.style.display = 'block'; kategoriaerr.innerHTML =returnedData['kategoria'];}else{kategoriaerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['model']!=""){modelerr.style.display = 'block'; modelerr.innerHTML =returnedData['model'];}else{modelerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['numer']!=""){numererr.style.display = 'block'; numererr.innerHTML =returnedData['numer'];}else{numererr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['data']!=""){dataerr.style.display = 'block'; dataerr.innerHTML =returnedData['data'];}else{dataerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['imie']!=""){imienazwiskoerr.style.display = 'block'; imienazwiskoerr.innerHTML =returnedData['imie'];}else{imienazwiskoerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['adres']!=""){adreserr.style.display = 'block'; adreserr.innerHTML =returnedData['adres'];}else{adreserr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['tel']!=""){telerr.style.display = 'block'; telerr.innerHTML =returnedData['tel']; }else{ telerr.style.display = 'none'; }
                    if(returnedData['email']!=""){emailerr.style.display = 'block'; emailerr.innerHTML =returnedData['email'];}else{emailerr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['opis']!=""){opiserr.style.display = 'block'; opiserr.innerHTML =returnedData['opis'];}else{opiserr.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['zal1']!=""){zal1err.style.display = 'block'; zal1err.innerHTML =returnedData['zal1'];}else{zal1err.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['zal2']!=""){zal2err.style.display = 'block'; zal2err.innerHTML =returnedData['zal2'];}else{zal2err.style.display = 'none';}
                    if(returnedData['zal3']!=""){zal3err.style.display = 'block'; zal3err.innerHTML =returnedData['zal3'];}else{zal3err.style.display = 'none';}

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
});
```

PHP:

```
$errors = array();

$naprawa = $_POST['rodzaj']; (i will do it for all data, but its work, when i echo this it is show in alert in error, so that code see value of variable)

$errors['rodzaj']="";
if($naprawa == '---')
{$errors['rodzaj'] = $f01[$j];} (here i fill my errors array and do something like this for all variables)
```

another example of filling array:

```
$errors['tel']="";
if (empty($telefon))
    {$errors['tel'] = $f14[$j];}
else if ((strlen($telefon) > 20) && (!empty($telefon)))
    {$errors['tel'] = $f05[$j];}
else if ((!preg_match('/^[0-9-\s\(\)\/]{1,20}+$/', $telefon)) && (!empty($telefon)) && (strlen($telefon) < 21))
    {$errors['tel'] = $f15[$j];}
```

Filling array work, because in string in alert in ajax are good texts
And there i send response:

```
echo json_encode($errors);
```

Here is what alert show me:

```
{"rodzaj":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 typ naprawy.","marka":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 mark\u0119.","kategoria":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 kategori\u0119 sprz\u0119tu.","model":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 model.","numer":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 numer fabryczny.","data":"","imie":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 imi\u0119.","adres":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 adres.","tel":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 numer telefonu.","email":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 adres email.","opis":"","zal1":"","zal2":"","zal3":""}
```

We see there name of field and value, for example: name -> rodzaj; value -> Prosimy wybra\u0107 typ naprawy. So response is ok. But problem is probably with parse in ajax. BTW. i want set this value in div as text, but when i try not using json but datetype text/html i get text of div like undefined. When i comment datatype i in console in browser i get:

> "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"

Anyone see there some defect?

Comment: Seems fine when I tested this in chrome: `var x = '{"rodzaj":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 typ naprawy.","marka":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 mark\u0119.","kategoria":"Prosimy wybra\u0107 kategori\u0119 sprz\u0119tu.","model":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 model.","numer":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 numer fabryczny.","data":"","imie":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 imi\u0119.","adres":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 adres.","tel":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 numer telefonu.","email":"Prosimy wprowadzi\u0107 adres email.","opis":"","zal1":"","zal2":"","zal3":""}'; JSON.parse(x);`

Comment: Yes its fine, but show me this in string in error.

Comment: What does `console.log(escape(data));` return?

Comment: When i try parse in error i get: `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: Escape return %5Bobject%20Object%5D

Comment: So it is an object.... not a string. It looks like jQuery is already converting it.

Comment: hmm maybe yes, because i use responseText in alert

Comment: So jQuery already converted it to the object so there is no reason to parse it. `success: function(data){ console.log(data);` should give you an object in the console.

Comment: So why always launch me error? Success launch when i change datatype to html, but without reason.

Comment: Because you are trying to parse an object, not a string. When you say html it is a string and can be parsed. `JSON.parse({"foo":"bar"})` vs `JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar"}')`. When Data type is set to JSON, jQuery does the JSON.parse() code for you.

Comment: So i dont parse it, but still dont launch success just error

Comment: You are saying it is  going into the Ajax error handler? If yes, what does `alert(escape(msg.responseText));` show?

Comment: Yes every time, in case use datatype html, but its wrong :D

Comment: escape in error show me: %0A%0A%uFEFF%7B%22rodzaj%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wybrac%20typ%20naprawy.%22%2C%22marka%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wybrac%20marke.%22%2C%22kategoria%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wybrac%20kategorie%20sprzetu.%22%2C%22model%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wprowadzic%20model.%22%2C%22numer%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wprowadzic%20numer%20fabryczny.%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22%22%2C%22imie%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wprowadzic%20imie.%22%2C%22adres%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wprowadzic%20adres.%22%2C%22tel%22%3A%22Prosimy%20wprowadzic%20numer%20telefonu.

Comment: That shows you have some weird character before your `{` which is what is probably breaking the parse.

Comment: ok i check this, can you tell me is that way to send formdata i correct?

Comment: hmm i dont see where some waired characters can be added to array $errors

Comment: Do you have any other `echo`'s in the php?

Comment: just one more, but second cant be send because it is something like this: `if(something){first echo;} else {second echo;}`

Comment: And you are not writing any headers to the page?

Comment: no i got `header('Content-type: application/json');` but i comment this, on php page

Comment: is that could be because i echo $lang in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `dataType: "json",` set in the jQuery Ajax options, jQuery will parse the response for you. It runs JSON.parse() for you.

So when you are doing `returnedData = JSON.parse(data);` you are trying to parse and Object and not a string.

There is no need to parse the data since it has already been converted from the string to the object by jQuery.

The reason why it works when you change the data type to something else is because the other data type returns a string, not an object, so the string can be parsed.

Now looking at why the Ajax handler is being triggered, that is normally caused by other characters getting outputted before or after the response. A way to check is to escape the output.

```
console.log(escape(msg.responseText));
```

You will see escape sequences before the `{` or after the `}`

So than you need to look at the PHP code and see what can be writing those characters out into the response.